# Errors with File plugin on PhoneGap application

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to save user information in a phonegap application but upon trying

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

    console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
    // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt'
    // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt'
    writeFile(fileEntry, null);

}, onErrorCreateFile);

}, onErrorLoadFs);
```

I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onErrorLoadFs is not defined

and on commenting it out I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onErrorCreateFile is not defined

and finally on commenting that out I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: writeFile is not defined

I am also running

```
window.addEventListener('filePluginIsReady', function(){ 

                        console.log('File plugin is ready');

                    requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {

                        console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
                        createFile(fs.root, "newTempFile.txt", false);

                }, onErrorCreateFile);
```

Incase the error was stemming from the file plugin not being ready but again I'm met with the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createFile is not defined

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for your time!

Comment: got any solutions for this ? `Uncaught ReferenceError: writeFile is not defined`

Comment: It's been about a year now since I've done anything with phonegap but I remember getting this error, can you send me your code and it might jog my memory on how to solve it?

Comment: Its giving me error `DOMException: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.`  i'm using chrome.

Comment: I think that's an error because you're testing in the browser, you can't save files while testing in the browser, have you tried a test build to see what you get?

Comment: No I did not. I'll try.

Comment: Keep me posted.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. :)

Comment: No bother, glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

onErrorCreateFile and onErrorLoadFs are functions that you need to define, e.g.:

```
function onErrorCreateFile() {
    console.log("Create file fail...");}

function onErrorLoadFs() {
    console.log("File system fail...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The `onErrorCreateFile`, `onErrorLoadFs`, `writeFile` and `readFile` methods need to be defined.  They are not included in the `sample-code` on the [website](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/).

On the same page though; the `writeFile` and `readFile` methods are written away from the `sample code`.  You can find it with a `find` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Good Luck.